# How to expire session if a have a setinterval js running?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've a page with a chart on it, the chart is update via JS using a setinterval of 20 seconds, now my session is not expiring, i've searched over the internet and didn't found something like this, how i would detect user inactivity with this chart running?

```
 setInterval(function(){


    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'php/grafico.php',
        success: function(e){
            e = JSON.parse(e);
            var linhas = e['linhas'];
            var label = new Array();
            for(var i = 1;i <= linhas; i++){
                label.push('');
            }
            var preco = new Array();
            for(var i = 1;i <= linhas; i++){
                preco.push(e[i]['preco']);
            }
            addData(chartGraph, preco, 0, label);
        }
    });


    var base = $('#Layer_base').height();
    $('#menuzinhu').css('min-height',base+'px');
}, 20000);
```

heres the setinterval function, how it will update the session so it will never expire, but i need it to expire.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Please include all relevant code.

Comment: Well, have u readed the question? i dont see any code need, but i edited with the chart code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a timeout, which is set to fire, the value of the time being how long you should wait for user input/events before deeming them inactive. You'd then reset the timeout whenever an event is triggered by the user, where you define what events signify user activity.

See below for an example, this is untested, but should see you on the right track.

```
var inactiveTime = 30000; //30 seconds

var interactionEvents = [
            "onload",
            "onmousemove",
            "onmousedown",
            "ontouchstart",
            "onclick",
            "onscroll",
            "onkeypress"
        ];
var timeoutId = null;

var finished = function () {
    //You'd put your logic in here to clear the session.
    //This gets fired when the user is deemed inactive.
    console.log("User inactive.");
};
//Keep track of if the timer has finished, handy if the user stays on 
//the page when this has finished, as you can compare it's value to
//detirmine if you should keep running the timeout. 
var hasFinished = false;

var reset = function () {

   if (hasFinished === true) {
        return;
   }

   //Clear any already running timeout
   clearTimeout(timeoutId); 

    //Start the new timeout
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {

        hasFinished = true;

        if (typeof(finished) === "function") {
            finished();
        }
    }, inactiveTime);

    //If events reset the timer, apply them

    //Attach events which will reset the timer
    for (var i = 0, max = interactionEvents.length; i < max; i++) {
        document[interactionEvents[i]] = reset();
    }

};

//Start the timer with this
reset();
```

Something like that!